# Javascript - getTime() not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a little quiz in html with 10 questions, each one in a separate html pages. At the point the user presses the START button in the index.html, I do the following:

```
var s = new Date();
sessionStorage.start_test = s;
```

and when he presses the FINISH button in page 10 of the quiz, I do:

```
var e = new Date();
sessionStorage.finish_test = e;
```

Finally, I have a page where the grade is displayed, and also the time spent in answering the quiz, with the following:

```
var start = sessionStorage.getItem( "start_test" );
var fin = sessionStorage.getItem( "finish_test" );
var time = fin.getTime() - start.getTime();
alert( time );
```

But this does not seem to work, as it is not displaying the javascript alert box, and in the console I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object Wed Jul 09 2014 13:38:06 GMT+0200 has no method 'getTime'
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Logging `typeof fin` will tell you all.

Comment: sessionStorage is string, not Date() instance. See : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24652916/2226755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*sessionStorage* is string, not *Date() instance*.

```
var start = new Date(sessionStorage.getItem( "start_test" ));
var fin = new Date(sessionStorage.getItem( "finish_test" ));
var time = fin.getTime() - start.getTime();
alert( time );
```

Answer (score 3):

When you add a Date object to local or session storage, it gets serialized into string, so, when you retrieve it with `getItem()` you get a string. To convert it back to Date object pass this string to `Date()` constructor:

```
var myDate = new Date( localStorage.getItem( 'foobardate' ) );
```